# Is there a way to disable message boxes in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an MFC application (using a legacy library that I can't change). When the application starts, it loads a couple of drivers and shows message boxes if some drivers couldn't be loaded. The loading of the drivers and the showing of the message boxes is done by a method inside the library that can't be changed (let's call this method Init). I would like to disable those message boxes (preventing them from "popping"). Is there something I could call before calling Init to disable Message Boxes temporarily and then re-enable them after?

(Note that if it is impossible to re-enable them after, I can very well live with that, I mostly want to disable them)

Thanks to all,

Note: If someone wonders about why I would like to do that, it is because my application exposes a COM interface and will be used by other applications. The only reason it is an application is that the library I use is much more easy to use when creating an MFC application (and not a dll). When it is called by my other applications, I don't want the message boxes to show, I just want to get the errors if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure whether this could work. I use it for subclassing some messageboxes not to preven them to popup and they are not from a dll.

I set a hook to capture message boxes before poping up:

```
HHOK hMessageBoxHook_ = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, 
                                         &CbtHookProc, 
                                         ::GetModuleHandle(NULL), 
                                         GetCurrentThreadId());
```

The new hook procedure (CbtHookProc) would be like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CbtHookProc(   int nCode, 
                                            WPARAM wParam, 
                                            LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(nCode < 0)
    {
        return ::CallNextHookEx(    hMessageBoxHook_, 
                                    nCode, 
                                    wParam, 
                                    lParam); 
    }

    switch(nCode)
    {
        case HCBT_CREATEWND: // a window is about to be created
            return -1;
    }

    return ::CallNextHookEx(    hMessageBoxHook_, 
                                nCode, 
                                wParam, 
                                lParam); 
}
```

From [microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for HCBT_CREATEWND:

> If the hook procedure returns a
>   nonzero value, the system destroys the
>   window

Then after calling Init you can remove the hook and message boxes will pop up again:

```
            ::UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMessageBoxHook_);
            hMessageBoxHook_ = 0;
```

As I told you I can't assure it works but give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to hook/unhook the calls to `MessageBox`/`MessageBoxEx`/etc. and just do nothing when these calls are made. Check [this guide](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx) for details on hooking API calls. In your case, I would specifically look at `Import Address Table` method, which is quite easy to implement and allows you to achieve the functionality you want.

You may also want to check Microsoft's own [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) library, but I'm not sure on whether it supports replacing API calls functionality.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using ODBC with MFC.  Everytime there was an error, a message box would pop up showing the error, which was fine if I wanted one.

However, if I didn't, I only needed to surround it with:

```
TRY
{
    // Call error-prone method
} 
CATCH ( CException, pEx )
{
    // Free resources
}
END_CATCH
```

The message box comes from the framework not knowing how to handle the exception.  Simply catch it and do as you wish with it.

Comment: thanks for the help but this doesn't solve my problem. The message boxes don't come from unhandled exceptions, they come from the library that itself catches the errors and shows message boxes. If it is possible, I want to disable or hide any future message box so that the library can't show them.